# Deleting last blank lines in SPOOL with DBMS_OUTPUT

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Using SPOOL and PL/SQL in SQL Developer (I must not use SQL Plus via command line) I need to create a file with some info. The problem is that at the end of the file I'm getting 2 blank lines with are causing me trouble when importing this file somewhere else.

Using the next code (called externally to avoid sql statements):

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
SET TERMOUT OFF;
SET HEAD OFF;
SET VERIFY OFF;
SET FEEDBACK OFF;

SPOOL 'C:\myfile.csv'

BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hello');
END;
/

SPOOL OFF;
```

I'm getting:

```
Hello
(blank line)
(blank line)
```

I can handle having 0 or 1 blank line, but not 2. I have tried `SET TRIMSPOOL ON` but SQL Developer skips this command and others too (TRIM, TRIMS, SQLBLANKLINES)

Comment: You should use DBMS_OUT.PUT instead of DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE to avoid the line feed/carriage return.

Comment: @Typo I also tried using `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT` but the buffer will not be printed until I use `DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE` and it adds the same 2 blank lines; or get the buffer with `DBMS_OUTPUT.GET_LINE` which leave me in the same place

Comment: Try removing all the blank lines from your script. Also try adding "set echo off", but note this is sensitive to the environment it runs in so might not work in SQLDeveloper.

Comment: Consider using UTL_FILE instead of DBMS_OUTPUT and SPOOL.

Comment: @TenG can't use `UTL_FILE` command since I need the files to be created in the client, not in the server since the database is somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

It really does look like it is not possible to remove that extra CRLF in SQL Developer. I can only suggest using SQLPlus which doesn't add that extra CRLF. If you absolutely can't use that, consider using sed to strip that last line.

For any further discussion and to save future readers' time, here are all the options I tried without success:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON TERMOUT OFF HEAD OFF FEEDBACK OFF VERIFY OFF
SET ECHO OFF NEWPAGE NONE PAGESIZE 0 RECSEP OFF --TRIMSPOOL ON
SPOOL 'myfile.txt'
--EXEC DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hello')
SELECT 'Hello' FROM DUAL;
SPOOL OFF
ED myfile.txt
```